# How to remove Autofac dependency error from eShop Project/Solution?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, event-bus

I am working on an eShopOnContainers Project. I dont need Rabbitmq,docker and EventBus in this project so I removed it. But I am facing some errors related to Autofac dependencies.

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            BuildWebHost(args)
                .MigrateDbContext<OrderingContext>((context, services) =>
                {
                    var env = services.GetService<IHostingEnvironment>();
                    var settings = 
services.GetService<IOptions<OrderingSettings>>();
                    var logger = 
services.GetService<ILogger<OrderingContextSeed>>();

                    new OrderingContextSeed()
                        .SeedAsync(context, env, settings, logger)
                        .Wait();
                })
                .MigrateDbContext<IntegrationEventLogContext>((_, __) => { 
})
                .Run();
        }

         public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)                
                 .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseHealthChecks("/hc")
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
                {
                    config.AddJsonFile("settings.json");
                    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                })
                .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, builder) =>
                {

builder.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                        builder.AddConsole();
                        builder.AddDebug();
                })
                 .UseApplicationInsights()
                .Build();
    }



    This is the Error for Autofac dependency.The main Error is Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException.How to remove Autofac dependency error from eShop Project/Solution?
  :
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException
  HResult=0x80131500
   Message=An error occurred during the activation of a particular 
 registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator 
 = HostedServiceExecutor (ReflectionActivator), Services = 
 [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostedServiceExecutor], Lifetime = 
 Autofac.Core.Lifetime.RootScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = 
 OwnedByLifetimeScope
  Source=Autofac
  StackTrace:
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 
 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, 
  Func`1 creator)
       at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
    at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance 
(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration 
registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration 
 registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext 
 context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
    at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext 
  context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
  at 

  Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions. 
  GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at 
 Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions. 
 GetReq uiredService[T] (IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost. 
<StartAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter. 
 HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions. 
 <RunAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at 

 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter 
.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions. 
<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter 
 .HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
   at Program.Main(String[] args) in 

 Inner Exception 1:
 DependencyResolutionException: An error occurred during the activation of a 
 particular registration. 
 See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = 
  IHostedService[] (DelegateActivator),
  Services = [System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ 
  [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService,
   Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=2.0.0.0, 
  Culture=neutral,
  PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]]], Lifetime = 
   Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = 
  ExternallyOwned

  Inner Exception 2:
  DependencyResolutionException: An error occurred during the activation of 
  a particular registration. 
 See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = 
 GracePeriodManagerService (ReflectionActivator),
  Services = [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService], Lifetime = 
  Autofac.Core.Lifetime.RootScopeLifetime,
   Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope

 Inner Exception 3:
  DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 
  'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 
  'Ordering.API.Infrastructure.HostedServices.GracePeriodManagerService' can 
    be invoked with the available services and parameters:
    Cannot resolve parameter 'BuildingBlocks.EventBus.Abstractions.IEventBus 
   eventBus' of constructor 'Void 

   .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[
   Services.Ordering.API.OrderingSettings], 
   BuildingBlocks.EventBus.Abstractions.IEventBus, 

   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[Ordering.API.Infrastructure
   .HostedServices.GracePeriodManagerService])'.
```

This is the Error for Autofac dependency.The main Error is Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException.How to remove Autofac dependency error from eShop Project/Solution?

Comment: As exception says, class GracePeriodManagerService which you are trying to resolve accepts IEventBus in constructor, which implementation you removed from DI container. What do you want it to use instead?

Comment: Thank You the reply .But I dont want EventBus in my code. Instead I want to use NServiceBus which is not implemented yet. If I want to remove IEventBus from contructor, then kindly suggest me the alternative for it.

Comment: Then I guess you need to implement a wrapper for NServiceBus. That wrapper will implement `IEventBus` interface, and you can register it in container instead of rabbitmq bus you removed.

Comment: @Evk Can we create this constructor without IEventBus?

Comment: Well you can - just remove it from constructor and remove all references to it from code of that class. Of course after doing it that class might not function as before, since you will remove part of its functionality...

Comment: @Evk Thanks. I am trying it.I Will Let you know if it works.

Comment: @Evk Thanks. The problem is solved. Your first reply of class GracePeriodManagerService was correct. I modified that class and my service is running now.